# Regression with error in covariates

Tags: regression, logistic, measurement-error, error-propagation

I am looking for some advice for a colleague who is dealing with regression models for which it is know, that the continuous covariate of interest $X_1$ was measured with error. More precisely, we know only know that the true $X_1$ lies within an interval $(X_L, X_R)$.

My first idea was to illustrate/describe the effect of the measurment error by fitting three models of the form
\begin{align*}
\text{Model 1:} \quad Y & = \beta_0 + \beta_1X_M + \beta_2 X_2  +... \\
\text{Model 2:} \quad Y & = \beta_0 + \beta_1X_L + \beta_2 X_2  +... \\
\text{Model 3:} \quad Y & = \beta_0 + \beta_1X_R + \beta_2 X_2  +... \\
\end{align*}
where $X_M$ is the midpoint of the interval.

What other regression methods are available that take into account that the true value of $X_1 \in (X_L, X_R)$? Specifically, when using linear regression models, logistic regression models, or generalized linear mixed models.

There is some information on the Wikipedia-Site about Errors-in-variables models (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errors-in-variables_models), but I'm not sure if those methods can be applied in this case.

Comment: You are looking for linear regression models with _interval-censored covariates_. See [here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12529872), for example.